# Object Factory with Properties Questions?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, scripting

This is just a general question.

As I understand it an object factory is just a place where your program can make and destroy predefined objects. I also understand it that this makes scripting and networking easier.

What is the pattern where I can say give me an object with this feature and that feature? Is that such a pattern? A friend of mine tells me that an object factory but I cant seem to find any info on an object factory with properties of the object. If this is a pattern and I'm not talking rubbish can anybody give me a good example, theory on it. This is also with a view for games design.

I think I just dont know what to Google.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
*quick example:*  (*sorry for the rather corny example*)
I want a spaceship with shields, missiles, and a radar.
Then I want a spaceship with warp drive, shields, and lots of cargo space.

Comment: Why do you mention scripting and tag the question as C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you know that you need a spaceship. This spaceship will have different gadgets attached to it, so you may want something like that:

```
class Spaceship {
public:
    void add(Gadget*);
};
```

maybe there will be different ship, so Spaceship will be the base class for the hierarchy. For example, you'll have scout ships, warships, fast interceptor and so on..

As for the gadget, maybe they will enhance some properties of the spaceship, so you need to know them *in advance*. I guess they will have a maximum speed, a cargo capacity and so on. I would add them to Spaceship class, that will look like:

```
class Spaceship {
public:
    void add(Gadget*);

    long getMaxSpeed() const;
    long getCargoCapacity() const;
    long getRadarRange() const;
};
```

Each spaceship will have different base values for this properties that you can vary according to the installed gadgets. So, they will give bonus or malus to said properties:

```
class SpaceshipGadget {
public:
    long getSpeedBonus() const; // this can be positive or negative
    long getCargoBonus() const;
    long getRadarBonus() const;
};
```

Maybe you don't even need a gadget hierarchy: if they only give bonus/malus you could assign them via the constructor and you're done.

Now, somewhere in the code, you'll have to build spaceships, to build gadgets and attach them to the spaceship (see `Spaceship::add` method). I suppose that the request that initiate the building process will come from the UI, so you'll know precisely what kind of gadget the user will want, since he/she will select from a list that you have to display.

In the end, you will end with a factory for spaceship and a factory for gadgets. The spaceship one will have many method such as

```
SpaceshipFactory {
public:
    Spaceship* buildCargo();
    Spaceship* buildWarship();
};

GadgetFactory {
public:
    Gadget* buildEnhancedRadar();
    Gadget* buildAntigravityCannons();
};
```

Anyway, you need to refine your design before thinking about code patterns. If you have trouble in explaining to others what you're trying to achieve, then something's still missing from the picture.

Answer (score 2):

The only think I can think of that even remotely describes what you're looking for is `QueryInterface`, used in COM, where you specify a type and if the object can produce an object that inherits from that interface, it does.

Apart from that, what you're saying doesn't make any sense whatsoever. You can't just ask a factory for an object that inherits from X interface, or anything else like that.

Edit:

Oh, I see. That has absolutely nothing to do with object factories. At all. What you'd want to do is order the spaceships by their properties, then enact a simple search. A bit mask and tries could be used to make this pretty fast, but I'll show code for the pretty inefficient version with no ordering.

```
class Spaceship {
    std::vector<std::string> properties;
public:
    bool HasProperty(string property) {
        for(int i = 0; i < properties.size(); i++) {
            if (properties[i] == property)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
std::vector<Spaceship*> GetShipsWithPropertiesFromList(std::vector<std::string> properties, std::vector<Spaceship*> spaceships) {
    for(int i = 0; i < properties.size(); i++) {
        std::vector<Spaceship*> list;
        for(int j = 0; j < spaceships.size(); j++) {
            if (spaceships[j]->HasProperty(properties[i]))
                list.push_back(spaceships[j]);
        }
        spaceships = list;
    }
    return spaceships;
}
```

EDIT: Forgot the return statement.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds vaguely like an.. err.. anti-pattern. But it sounds similar to the [service locator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's just a factory with arguments to the creation method:

```
class ShipFactory
{
    function Create(Shield shield, WeaponConfiguration weapons, Engine engine)
    {
        // Return an instance with the appropriate configuration
    }
}
```

The dependencies (shield etc) may well be created using factories of their own:

```
class ShieldFactory
{
    function Shield Create();
}

class WeaponsFactory
{
    function WeaponConfiguration Create();
}

class EngineFactory
{
    function Engine Create();
}
```

Resulting in something like:

```
shield = shieldFactory.Create();
weapons = weaponsFactory.Create();
engine = engineFactory.Create();

ship = shipFactory.Create(shield, weapons, engine);
```

Or you implement the dependency management some other way, but still, the way I see it, this is just using the factory pattern with parameters. The reason for using factories instead of just using object constructors may not be obvious, but the idea is that by using factories, you can declare those as dependencies and inject the factories from some sort of configuration object, effectively abstracting away the construction logic from your game logic.